Reduction of structure group of frame bundle under almost complex structure for different metric signatures
I get that there is an isomorphism between $SO(n,m,\mathbb{C})$ for all $n,m$ where $n+m=k$ and $k$ is some fixed integer. What I'm asking is slightly more nuanced. Suppose we have some orientable $k$ ( k is even) dimensional manifold $M$ which admits metrics of different signatures. Then depending upon the chosen signature the linear frame bundle can be reduced to a principal:
$SO(n,m,\mathbb{R})$ bundle. Now suppose $M$ admits an almost complex structure, as I understand it, this gives us a reduction for certain cases of chosen signature:
$$SO(k,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow U(k/2)$$
$$SO(k/2,k/2,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow U(k/2)$$
but the similarity in the reductions for the different cases makes me wonder if this is the case for all chosen signatures? Is there some similar isomorphism going on as for $SO(n,m,\mathbb{C})$ case?
What about the lorentzian case $SO(1,k-1,\mathbb{R})$?
EDIT: it seems I may be wrong about the split signature case, nonetheless im interested in what happens when you force an almost complex structure onto a lorentzian signatured manifold. does any sub portion of $U(k/2)$ survive? If its lorentzian id intuitively expect a $U(k/2 - 1)$ portion to survive possibly. i.e. that a subset of the almost complex strucure $J$ would be compatible compatible with the lorentzian metric and connection?

It is important to observe that there is not just a relation between existence of some structures and existence of a reduction, but the reduction equivalently encodes some kind of geometric structure. In the case you are thinking about, we have a manifold of even dimension $k=2\ell$, so the standard linear frame bundle has structure group $GL(2\ell,\mathbb R)$. Now you have the following equivalences of structures and reductions to groups:

pseudo-Riemannian metrics of signature $(p,q)$ with $p+q=2\ell$ $\iff$ redcution to $O(p,q)\subset GL(2\ell,\mathbb R)$
almost complex structure $\iff$ reduction to $GL(\ell,\mathbb C)\subset GL(2\ell,\mathbb R)$
almost complex structure + Hermitian metric of (complex) signature $(r,s)$ with $r+s=\ell$ $\iff$ reduction to $U(r,s)\subset GL(2\ell,\mathbb R)$
almost complex structure + complex Riemannian metric (i.e. complex bilinear symmetric form on each tangent space) $\iff$ reduction so $SO(\ell,\mathbb C)\subset GL(2\ell,\mathbb R)$.

So you see that a combination of two structures that correspond to reductions of structure group (here almost complex structure and pseudo-Riemannian metric) corresponds to a further reduction of structure group only if compatibility conditions between the two structures are satisfied. (In particular, it does not make sense to thinks about existence of the two structures separately.) And indeed, here there are two different possible compatibility conditions: Denoting the metric by $g$ and the almost complex structure by $J$, the first possibility is that $g(JX,JY)=g(X,Y)$ (which by linear algebra is possibile only if the signature of $g$ is of the form $(2r,2s)$ with $r+s=\ell$. Then you can extend $g$ to a Hermitian metric and get a reduction to $U(r,s)$ (usually referred to as an "almost Hermitian structure"). The other possibility is that $g(JX,JY)=-g(X,Y)$ (which may happen for any signature) and then you can extend $g$ to a complex bilinear  form in each point and get a reduction to $SO(\ell,\mathbb C)$.

Thank you, that clears up a lot. if you are interested. I was looking at reductions of $FFM$ the frame bundle of the frame bundle over FM. Since FM is always parallelizable we have the AC structure, but here we also have a splitting of the tangent bundle of FM by the connection in FM. was teying to ascertain for a general orientable base space with metric what our structure group looks like for FFM.
